# Get mantissa and exponent of double/float in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, floating-point, double

How can I access the mantissa and exponent of a double in kotlin?

A multiplatform option would be ideal, but the Double class has no such methods/properties.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this other than on the JVM, but it's fairly straightforward there with `java.lang.Math` and `java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits`.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin provides the [`toBits()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-bits.html) function, which is just a wrapper of the JDK's [`doubleToLongBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)). You can see from the docs for `doubleToLongBits`:

> Bits 62-52 (the bits that are selected by the mask `0x7ff0000000000000L`) represent the exponent. Bits 51-0 (the bits that are selected by the mask `0x000fffffffffffffL`) represent the significand (sometimes called the mantissa) of the floating-point number.

So you can write properties that extract the values for you:

```
val Double.mantissa get() = toBits() and 0x000fffffffffffff
val Double.exponent get() = toBits() and 0x7ff0000000000000 shr 52

fun main() {
    println(1.0.mantissa)
    println(1.0.exponent)
}
```

Output:

```
0
1023
```

Note that these are the raw IEEE-754 encoded values. You will need to convert them according to the IEEE-754 spec if you want the numerical values.

Comment: This is very helpful, however I do not seem to be able to correctly interpret it. If I have understood the specification correctly, 1023 must be subtracted from the exponent, but the mantissa is still not accurate for most numbers? For example the mantissa of `5.0` is `1125899906842624`. How am I supposed to interpret this?

Comment: You're in danger of sending me down a rabbit-hole investigating this too. I don't have time to look into it further right now but it's an interesting question. Here's the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) if you want to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest common for all programming languages solution:

`val mantissa = doubleValue - doubleValue.toInt()`

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, by mantissa I meant the significant digits as an integer